# how to retrieve distinct root entity row count in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have to show Employee and his Project in dropdown to employee in the right ride of tabular format. In the top i need to show number of records. So, I am doing two queries, one for retrieving  count and another for retrieving employee and his project.finally, the **total count** comes **employee*project** count.

If an employee has 3 projects then it counts to 3. But I need only employee count. And I am retriving distinct `Employee` object, that employee object has list of `Project`.

I used `.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` to get like this.

Please help me to get only **employee count** instead of **employee*project**, I am struggling with this.

My COde is,

```
public Collection fetchEmployeeWithProject(final List condition,
            final PaginationCriteria pageCriteria)
            throws DataAccessLayerException {
                 Session session = this.getPersManager().getCurrentSession();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "employee")
                .createAlias(
                        "employee.empProject", "empProject",
                        CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN).createAlias(
                        "empProject.Project", "project",
                        CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
        criteria = this.addMultipleSeachCriteria(criteria, condition);
        this.buildPaginatedCriteria(criteria, pageCriteria);
        List lst = criteria.list();
        session.clear();
    return lst;
    }

protected Criteria buildPaginatedCriteria(Criteria criteria,
            PaginationCriteria pageCriteria) throws DataAccessLayerException {

        logger.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "buildPaginatedCriteria::Begin");

        if (pageCriteria != null) {

            if (!pageCriteria.isFetchAll()) {

                if (pageCriteria.getTotalRecords() == 0)
                    pageCriteria.setTotalRecords(((Integer) criteria
                            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                            .uniqueResult()).intValue());
                criteria.setProjection(null);
                criteria.setFirstResult(
                        pageCriteria.getFirstRecordOfCurrentPage())
                        .setMaxResults(pageCriteria.getRecordsPerPage());
            }

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pageCriteria.getSortBy()))
                criteria.addOrder(pageCriteria.isSortDescending() ? Order
                        .desc(pageCriteria.getSortBy()) : Order
                        .asc(pageCriteria.getSortBy()));

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pageCriteria.getSecondarySortBy())) {
                criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(pageCriteria.getSecondarySortBy()));
            }

            if (pageCriteria.isCached()) {
                criteria.setCacheable(true).setCacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL);
            }
        }
        criteria
                .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        logger.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "buildPaginatedCriteria::End");

        return criteria;
    }
```

These are the methods that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in Hibernate when doing joins and trying to count. The problem with `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` is that it removes equal rows, but since you did a join, some rows have different fields although it is the same entity.

If you want to count and do joins at the same time, put all the objects retrieved into a `Set`. This way the duplicates will go away. Then you can do `Set#size` to count.

Or you can use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and write your query manually.

Maybe if you edit your question and add the actual queries that you are creating we can help you further.

**Update**

Add this after: `List lst = criteria.list();`

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
employeeSet.addAll(lst);
return employeeSet;
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to get distinct root entities.what my problem is If i specify no of records as 10, if the first employee has 10 projects associated, only first person is listed not any other.I need to retrive 10 Employee..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you say. Your problem is that you only receive 10 rows? In this case, you can try with `Criteria#setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, but I would recommend you to split the retrieving of the data into more queries of X rows each. Otherwise you can suffer a `PermGem` or `OutOfMemory` Exception